# Objective C - scraping a webpage for Title, Description and list of URL for all images and their sizes

Tags: objective-c, web-scraping, tfhpple

I'm trying to use [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) to scrape webpages , but I don't know the syntax for

`searchWithXPathQuery`

I need to get the Title, description , and a list of images from an arbitrary webpage,

The code currently is similar to

```
NSData  * data      =     [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

TFHpple * doc       = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];

NSArray *arr =    [doc searchWithXPathQuery:@"//title"];
TFHppleElement *titleElem = [arr firstObject];
NSString *titleStr = titleElem.text;
NSLog(@"arr = %@",arr);
```

I would expect this to retrieve all nodes

```
arr = [doc searchWithXPathQuery:@"//"];
```

but it isn't.

I don't care changing the framework to another one.

What is the best strategy to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/nolanw/HTMLReader

```
    NSURL *sUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"];
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:sUrl];
    NSString *markUp = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[htmlData bytes]];
    HTMLDocument *site = [HTMLDocument documentWithString:markUp];
    NSString *siteTitle = [site firstNodeMatchingSelector:@"title"].textContent;
```